# How to retain 3D Viewport and Outliner settings while changing workspaces?

Tags: interface, workspaces

I often cycle through Workspaces layout tabs, 3D Viewport and Outliner are changing their appearance. Is there a way to fix it?

For example, in the first tab I use object mode with particular camera view and look dev shading, when I switch tab all this changes to edit mode, camera changes angle and shading changes to solid. I don’t need it.

Comment: Each workspace saves its own view settings, if you save them with the startup file they'll be remembered next time you start if you turn off the *Load UI* option. You can also erase all but one workspace, save your view settings as desired then duplicate it and create new ones from that template

Comment: Is there a way for workspace to inherit view settings? For example if I change view settings during project, I want all other tab to change it due to my current settings.

Comment: Workspace may have multiple viewports and 3D views all with different settings, there is no way to unequivocally map them across non homogeneous layouts

Comment: Eh... If only...

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there's still no native option in Blender to retain viewport position between workspaces. You'd need an add-on for that.

Try [Synchronize Workspaces - Blender Add-on](https://m-soluyanov.gumroad.com/l/afoty), damn useful.

An icon added to the top bar toggles synchronization of viewports On/Off.